# Who created the Korean Unification Flag?

Tags: korea, north-korea, flags

*Wikipedia:* The Unification Flag is a flag designed to represent all of Korea when North and South Korea participate as one team in sporting events.

Still according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Unification_Flag#Use_in_other_contexts), in recent years the North Korean government is using this flag outside of the sport context, at highly political border events.

[image: Korean Unification Flag]

Who created this flag?
In particular, was the flag created more by a side than the other?

Comment: I'm quite surprised NK is using it out of context: doing so immediatly disqualifies it from its intended purpose...

Answer (score 1):

According to this wiki the man who originally coined the idea was [Han yongun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Yong-un). during the  3.1 march: [한반도기 (Wikipedia)](https://ko.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%95%9C%EB%B0%98%EB%8F%84%EA%B8%B0).
But dismissed the idea and used the Korean flag instead.

It was discussed again in 1989 to be used as the flag for the formation of the Korean unified team for the 1990 Beijing Asian games. 
 and first used at the world Table Tennis Championships in Japan in 1991.

Comment: Would you mind linking words to Wikipedia in order to avoid ambiguity. In particular, please link "Han yongun" and "Korean flag" to the right pages, thanks!

Comment: @nic - you should feel free to insert these links, so long as they increase the value of the answer.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: I used my limited Korean skills to guess who the man is on Wikipedia, but I am still unsure what Jujumuffin refers to by saying "the Korean flag".